# Firebase Authentication and Database with Django

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication with email and password to sign up users, but want them to be able to sign in using Phone number and password. Their phone number,email and password is stored in the RealTime Database. I used the 'sign_in_with_email_and_password' because I don't know how else to sign in authenticated users, since I'm new to Django. Any help would be appreciated.

services.py

```
from . import views
from .models import Product
import pyrebase

def firebase_key():

#configuring firebase
config = {
'apiKey' : "AIzaSyBd31FZCtpdRuxmkY0uiitJap1Mcet1iDA",
'authDomain' : "registration-c3373.firebaseapp.com",
'databaseURL' : "https://registration-c3373.firebaseio.com",
'projectId' : "registration-c3373",
'storageBucket' : "registration-c3373.appspot.com",
'messagingSenderId' : "123962731629",
'appId' : "1:123962731629:web:c4cc2ed965b1031daa2364"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

return firebase
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from . import services
import pyrebase
from django.contrib import auth
from .models import Product

authe = services.firebase_key().auth()
database = services.firebase_key().database()

def postsign(request):

 number = request.POST.get('number')
 password = request.POST.get("password")


 try:
     #allowing only authorised users to log in to the site
     user = authe.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,password)



 except:
     msg = "Invalid Credentials"
     return render(request, "Login.html", {"msg":msg})
 print(user['idToken'])
 session_id = user['idToken']
 request.session['uid'] = str(session_id)
 return render(request,"Welcome.html")

def postSignUp(request):
email = request.POST.get('email')
password = request.POST.get("password")
number = request.POST.get('number')

#authenticating users
try:
    user = authe.create_user_with_email_and_password(email,password)
except:
    message = "Unable to create account, please try again later"
    return render(request,"SignUp.html",{"msg":messsage})
    uid = user['localId']

data = {"email":email, "password":password, "phone":number}

database.child("users").child(number).set(data)


return render(request, "Login.html")
```